# Can't buy lumber for my house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I did a mission for the Dawnguard where I was to kill a vampire at Half-Moon Mill. And now later in the game, I can't buy sawn logs for my house.

Answer (score 3):

The half-moon mill is not the only mill in skyrim. There are several other lumber mills where you can go to buy lumber for your house.

A list of lumber mills below:

- Anga's Mill, west of Windhelm.
- Deadwood Lumber Mill, Falkreath.
- Solitude Sawmill, Haafingar.
- Half-Moon Mill, Falkreath, at Lake Ilinalta.
- Heartwood Mill, The Rift, at Lake Honrich.
- Dragon Bridge Lumber Camp, Haafingar.
- Mixwater Mill, Eastmarch.
- Riverwood's lumber mill.
- Morthal's lumber mill.
- Ivarstead's lumber mill.

Source: [Skyrim Wiki: List of Lumber Mills](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lumber_Mill)

Comment: Don't forget you can also buy it from your steward, who lives in your house.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can buy lumber from your steward.  That's usually much easier because they hang out at your house, requires no travel, and is available instantly.